# Counting the numbers data that appears in all tables in same database sql server

Tags: sql-server

I know how to show all the list for all the tables in a same database, but what I want here is to compare all the column(CPI_Name) for all tables in a same database to check if there is any data is same.

For example, there is two CPI_Name column from two different tables or more:

[image]

[image]

This are the way I use to compare between two tables in a same database.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables

SELECT CPI_Name FROM CarryIn
INTERSECT
SELECT CPI_Name FROM CarryOut
```

Let say I want to check for variable 1 has appear how many times in both tables, what should I do?

OR

If I want to know if 1 has appear how many times in ALL TABLES in same database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(20) = 'CPI_Name'
DECLARE @VariableValue VARCHAR(20) = '1'
SELECT 'select count(*) from ' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME + ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @VariableValue)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = @ColumnName
```

You will have to loop through the rows returned and execute the SQL returned.

Comment: the output is : select count(*) from dbo.TableA WHERE CPI_Name = 1

Comment: Yes, you will have to execute this statement to see how many records have this value for the column supplied.

Comment: Thanks!  you save my day !! newbie in mssql need guys like you !